# Wordpress facebook login in Android app

Tags: android, wordpress, facebook, facebook-login

I am currently developing an app interact with word press service. And when I tried to call facebook connect in my application via word press user api, it gives error. Here is how I did:

First I connect my facebook account with permissions to get the access token. This step is success and the token is valid here. I have tried to use this token to get user profile with facebook "/me?fields=id,name,email", it returned correct data.

```
        mFacebookCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        btnFacebookSignIn.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "user_friends", "email");
        btnFacebookSignIn.registerCallback(mFacebookCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                handleFacebookLoginSuccess();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            }
        });
```

Then I use the token to connect facebook with word press service:

URL: http:///api/user/fb_connect/?access_token=

Json returned: {"status":"ok","msg":"Your 'access_token' did not return email of the user. Without 'email' user can't be logged in or registered. Get user email extended permission while joining the Facebook app."}

==================================

Note:

- I have included "email" permission above and can get the email field via "/me".
- You can see details of facebook connect in word press here https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-user/

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What API is that supposed to be, that you say you are calling via `URL: http:///api/user/fb_connect/?access_token=` ?

Comment: @CBroe, Yes, I am calling http://.../fb_connect/?access_token= to connect facebook. And the access token param I get from facebook authorize on the first step.

Comment: @joe138 Did you get the solution of this ? I face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution of it.
In my case, I have just disable the SSL certificate in User.php file in fb_connect method.

`// Enable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, $enable_ssl);`

change to
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

I am using the development server with prefix "http://" instead of "https://".